# Truffle Test Fail, multiple contracts

Tags: dapp-development

I have 3 failing tests, of 8 total, all work on first contract, none on the second.  any insights why i can get a remix 'success' on the contract, and a test  failure with revert?

[github link:] (https://github.com/shaddow1201/CredentialVerify)
[error shown:] (https://www.screencast.com/t/KOizhm55HX)

2_deploy_contracts.js detail:
    var CredentialOrgFactory = artifacts.require("CredentialOrgFactory");
    var CredentialFactory = artifacts.require("CredentialFactory");
    //var ApplicantFactory = artifacts.require("ApplicantFactory");
    //var ProcessCredentials = artifacts.require("ProcessCredentials");

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(CredentialOrgFactory);
  deployer.deploy(CredentialFactory);
  //deployer.deploy(ApplicantFactory);
  //deployer.deploy(ProcessCredentials);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the function only callable by the owner of the contract, which is reverting. Plus, it has no value with a view function.

Comment: aren't the tests ran using the owner?

Comment: They are run using the first account in the array, if you are deploying the contract from a factory, the factory is the owner of the contract. The `msg.sender` will be whoever deployed it.

Comment: thanks!  that helped!  changed to functions to public and the tests passed.  Appreciate.

Comment: Thanks, if you found the answer useful could you accept my answer please?